# Lock operation on an execution queue until finished

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, locking

I'm setting up a blocking operation on user login after many failed attempts, using spring boot. The operation runs smoothly, but is opened to an multithreaded attack. If the attacker spawns multiple login threads, I need to increment the failure counter, which needs to be persisted on the database. The problem is that if multiple attempts occurr in the same time, the user initial attempts will be equal to everyone.

I've tried to use LockProvider, which blocks multiple attempts, but I find no way of consistently incrementing the counter for this case.

The code follows something like

```
LockConfiguration lockConfiguration = new LockConfiguration(userName, Instant.MAX);
Optional<SimpleLock> lock = lockProvider.lock(lockConfiguration);
try{
    if(lock.isPresent()){
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
        user.incrementAttempts();
        userRepository.save(user);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Multiple login detected")
    }
} finally {
    lock.ifPresent(SimpleLock::unlock);
}
```

I need that when there are multiple attempts of login, the counter is incremented. Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: Is it really so important to prevent a few extra login attempts?

Comment: It's a PCI compliance which the cliente required.